# Who can view private documents in My Site?

Tags: permissions, my-site

When users create their "My Site", they can store some documents in their private space.
Is there any other user who can view it? or work around (maybe like going to central administration and adding user as site collection administrator to the My Site site collection?

Or it is really private area that no one can view other than the My Site owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default its only for the user, site collection admins and farm admins. But like any list in SharePoint permissions can be changed.
/WW

Answer (score 1):

I assume that any user configured in Central Admin / Operations / Policy for Web Application has privileges as well.